# Defining relations on same table Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have a refferal system in my application.ie, One user can reffer other.

**Users table**

```
id name 
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

**Referrals table**

```
id referrer_id referee_id
1      1           2
2      2           3
```

I want to show the referrals made by a user.

*User Model*

```
public function referrals()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Referral','referee_id','id');
}
```

*Referral Model*

```
public function referrer_user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Modules\User\Models\User','referrer_id','id');
}

public function referee_user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Modules\User\Models\User','referee_id','id');
}
```

Defining hasMany relationship in User model and belongsTo relationship in Referrals Model, I'am not getting the desired result.

```
@foreach($user->referrals as $key => $referral)
    {{dd($referral->referee_user->name)}}
@endforeach
```

This returning me the name of user itself(referrer) not the referee

Comment: Are you sure that you are correctly creating a Referral? Maybe you are switching ids upon creation? So far your code seem ok to me.

Comment: No thats correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring the ManyToMany relationship the wrong way.

Anyways, it'll be much easier and efficient the following way.

```
id  name  referred_by
 1   abc    null
 2   def     1
 3   gfd     2
```

User Model

```
/**
 * Who did he bring onboard?
*/
public function referrals(){
  return $this->hasMany('....User', 'referred_by');
}

//Who brought him onboard..
public function referree(){
  return $this->belongsTo('...User', 'referred_by');
}
```

Just check out the appropriate syntax.

Comment: Yeah I changed and its working.I didn't get that referee() relation.what do u meant by that in the user model?

Comment: A user may refer many users (referrals).
A user may be referred by some other user (referee)